# How many of the last 5 elements are checked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Why can't I do this?

```
$(this).prevAll("input").slice(-5).is(":checked").length
```

I want to find out how many of the last 5 inputs are checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is); `.is` tests for a condition and returns a boolean value. Use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to get matching items:

```
$(this).prevAll("input").slice(-5).filter(":checked").length
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is) returns true/false based on whether any of the elements in a set matches a selector, not the set of elements itself.

You probably meant to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) instead, which returns a set of elements that match your selector:

```
$(this).prevAll("input").slice(-5).filter(":checked").length
```